# Search for 3 things close to each other using regular expressions for sublime

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, plaintext

I am trying to search for three strings close to each other in regular expressions, I am using Sublime text 2, just using the regular expressions command line at the bottom of the screen.  I have been tinkering but can't quite get it.
I am searching through 10,000 lines of code, the strings help me find certain errors
I am using sublime 2, I can get 2 things using

```
\word1.(?:..){1,750}?word2\b
```

when I try this

```
\word1.(?:..){1,750}?word2\b | \word2.(?:..){1,750}?word3\b
```

it gives me an `OR` statement and I'm looking for an `AND` statement

So far this is what I have tried

```
\word1.(?:..){1,750}?word2\b | \word2.(?:..){1,750}?word3\b
```

Comment: may we see the strings that you want, perhaps in the context of some of the other data in which they are embedded?

Comment: `OR` statement is expressed with `|` in regex, but `AND` is expressed with `.*` and is trickier since we have to account for 2 possible positions: `1.*2` and `2.*1`. With 3 alternatives, it is even worse. However, if all must be present on a line, you can use lookaheads: `(?m)^(?=.*1)(?=.*2)(?=.*3).*` to match that line. If there can be newlines, you need to enforce multiline mode using `(?s)` an the beginning of the pattern.

Comment: Does this work? `\word1.(?:..){1,750}?word2\b(?:..){1,750}?word3\b`

Comment: @Diego it did not work unfortunately, i threw it in regexr and sublime and neither came up with anything, the three strings I am using are very clearly close to one another, I'll keep tinkering, First week messing around with Regexr

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for `word1(?:.){1,750}?word2(?:.){1,750}?word3`?

http://regexr.com/3bp45